# why is dependent entity with no principal entity not throwing a foreign key error on insert?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF 6 and a mix of attributes and Fluent API to map a legacy database that I have to read/write to. I've done the relationship mapping in Fluent API.

I have also made each entity inherit from an abstract BaseClass, so that I can interact with the entities in a more abstract way.

The base class:

```
public abstract class BaseClass {

}
```

For whatever reason, there are number of tables I need to interact with where the table identity column is not the same column as the primary key for the table. I also can't change the structure of the tables in the underlying database, as it is used by a number of other applications over which I have no control.

I have several different types of principal-dependent one-to-many relationships defined, where each of the Dependents each needs to have a Principal, and the Principal has many optional Dependents.

As an example, the classes in question all look something like this:

```
[Table("PrincipalTable")]
public class Principal : BaseClass {
    
    public int TableId { get; set; } // this is the identity column

    [Key]
    public string PrincipalId { get; set; }

    // more properties

    public virtual ICollection<Dependent> Dependents { get; set; }
}

[Table("DependentTable")]
public class Dependent : BaseClass {

    [Key]
    public int DependentId { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string PrincipalId { get; set; }

    // more properties

    public virtual Principal Principal { get; set; }
}
```

The foreign key relationship for each of these pairs is defined in Fluent API as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Principal>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Dependents)
    .WithRequired(e => e.Principal)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.PrincipalId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

When getting a record of type Principal, it correctly returns its Dependents as well, if there are any. So far, so good.

However, I also need to prevent any Dependent from being added without a valid Principal record. This does not appear to be working correctly.

The add method:

```
public async Task<bool> Add<T>(T entity, Type entityType) where T : class
{
    try
    {
        var contextSet = context.Set(entityType);
        contextSet.Add(entity);
                
        var result = await context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return result > 0;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

In testing this, I can add a Dependent record with a completely bogus PrincipalId, and no foreign key error is thrown.

The "Type entityType" parameter is necessary because T is not known until runtime, and using the generic "context.Set()" returns a DbSet of type BaseClass, not the desired derived entity type. I've confirmed that "context.Set(entityType)" returns the correct DbSet by stepping through the code.

This appears to happen whether the Principal primary key is a string, an int, a decimal, or a composite key.

**Edit (4/4/22):**

As an example, here is one of the entities in question:

```
[Table("hdepben")]
public class SageHrDependentBenefit : SageHrEntityBase
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id_col", Order = 0)]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id_col { get; set; }

    [Column("d_benecode", Order = 1)]
    [StringLength(10)]
    [Required]
    public string d_benecode { get; set; }

    [Column("d_chadate")]
    public DateTime? d_chadate { get; set; }

    [Column("d_company")]
    [StringLength(3)]
    [Required]
    public string d_company { get; set; }

    [Column("d_coverage")]
    [Required]
    public decimal d_coverage { get; set; }

    [Column("d_depid", Order = 5)]
    [Required]
    public decimal d_depid { get; set; }

    [Column("d_effdate")]
    public DateTime? d_effdate { get; set; }

    [Column("d_empno", Order = 7)]
    [StringLength(9)]
    [Required]
    public string SageId { get; set; }

    [Column("d_expdate")]
    public DateTime? d_expdate { get; set; }

    [Column("d_misc1")]
    [StringLength(10)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    public string d_misc1 { get; set; }

    [Column("d_misc2")]
    [StringLength(10)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    public string d_misc2 { get; set; }

    [Column("d_misc3")]
    [StringLength(10)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    public string d_misc3 { get; set; }

    [Column("d_misc4")]
    [StringLength(10)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    public string d_misc4 { get; set; }

    [Column("d_premium")]
    [Required]
    public decimal d_premium { get; set; }

    [Column("d_comments")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    public string d_comments { get; set; }

    [Column("d_courtord")]
    [StringLength(1)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    public string d_courtord { get; set; }

    [Column("d_covfrom")]
    public DateTime? d_covfrom { get; set; }

    [Column("d_covto")]
    public DateTime? d_covto { get; set; }

    [Column("d_ordnumb")]
    [StringLength(25)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    public string d_ordnumb { get; set; }

    [Column("d_crtnotes")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    public string d_crtnotes { get; set; }

    [Column("lckuser")]
    [StringLength(4)]
    public string lckuser { get; set; }

    [Column("lckstat")]
    [StringLength(1)]
    public string lckstat { get; set; }

    [Column("lckdate")]
    public DateTime? lckdate { get; set; }

    [Column("lcktime")]
    [StringLength(8)]
    public string lcktime { get; set; }

    public virtual SageHrDependent Dependent { get; set; }

    public virtual SageHrBenefits Benefit { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the foreign key mapping in Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SageHrDependent>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Benefits)
    .WithRequired(e => e.Dependent)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.d_depid)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

modelBuilder.Entity<SageHrBenefits>()
    .HasMany(e => e.DependentBenefits)
    .WithRequired(e => e.Benefit)
    .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.d_benecode, e.SageId })
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

This DependentBenefit entity is foreign-key-mapped both to a Dependent entity and a Benefit entity.

The test in question involves posting a dto to a Web API endpoint that wraps all interaction with this database. Once posted, that dto gets mapped to the entity as follows:

```
public static SageHrDependentBenefit MapToSage(this DependentBenefitDTO dto)
{
    return dto == null ? null : new SageHrDependentBenefit()
    {
        d_benecode = dto.BenefitCode ?? "",
        d_chadate = dto.ChangeDate,
        d_comments = dto.Comments ?? "",
        d_company = dto.Company ?? "",
        d_courtord = dto.d_courtord ?? "",
        d_coverage = dto.CoverageAmount,
        d_covfrom = dto.CoveredFrom,
        d_covto = dto.CoveredTo,
        d_crtnotes = dto.crtnotes ?? "",
        d_depid = dto.DependentId,
        d_effdate = dto.EffectiveDate,
        d_expdate = dto.ExpirationDate,
        id_col = dto.TableId,
        lckdate = dto.lckdate,
        lckstat = dto.lckstat,
        lcktime = dto.lcktime,
        lckuser = dto.lckuser,
        d_misc1 = dto.Misc1 ?? "",
        d_misc2 = dto.Misc2 ?? "",
        d_misc3 = dto.Misc3 ?? "",
        d_misc4 = dto.Misc4 ?? "",
        d_ordnumb = dto.OrderNumber ?? "",
        d_premium = dto.DependentPremium,
        SageId = dto.EmployeeId ?? ""
   };
}
```

And the bad data being posted to the webservice (that should be throwing the foreign key error):

```
public static DependentBenefitDTO GetBadNoBeneDummyDependentBenefit(int dependentId)
{
    return new DependentBenefitDTO()
    {
        BenefitCode = "BADDATA",
        ChangeDate = new DateTime(2022, 01, 03),
        Company = "TEC",
        DependentId = dependentId,
        EffectiveDate = new DateTime(2021, 08, 01),
        ExpirationDate = new DateTime(2099, 12, 31),
        EmployeeId = GetDummyEmployeeId()
    };
}

public static DependentBenefitDTO GetBadNoDepDummyDependentBenefit()
{
    return new DependentBenefitDTO()
    {
        BenefitCode = "INH3000",
        ChangeDate = new DateTime(2022, 01, 03),
        Company = "TEC",
        DependentId = 10000,
        EffectiveDate = new DateTime(2021, 08, 01),
        ExpirationDate = new DateTime(2099, 12, 31),
        EmployeeId = "123456"
    };
}
```

There is no Benefit entity with a benefit code of "BADDATA", and no Dependent entity with DependentId of 10000. However, neither the data with no Benefit parent entity, nor the data with no Dependent parent entity throws a foreign key error.

As mentioned, when getting data from this same db/context, all the expected entities are correctly associated and returned.

Stepping through the code, I've confirmed that the mapping is correctly assigning the values as well.

**End edits 4/4/22**

Why is no error being thrown on insert?

Comment: Could you post some of your test code to check exactly what you are doing wrong?

Comment: @jalepi - sure thing. I just edited the question with some code that is currently not passing tests.

Comment: where is the test code?

Comment: The actual integration test? I don't know that that's strictly relevant here - I'm stepping through the code to add the entity to the context, and the bad data is not throwing an error as it should on insert, whether I try to add it from the integration test or not.

Comment: Without the code where you interact with your dbcontext, inserting data, checking the test setup if table is clean or erased before, it will be difficult. The most obvious thing I can guess is the tests might be running against the same database. Do you have proper setup and tear down?